# AngularJS $routeChangeError not being called or executed

Tags: angularjs, routes, single-page-application, angularjs-routing

I have some API calls to make in my router before my controller loads and my view renders. Here's what I'm trying:

app.js:

```
.when('/settings', {
    templateUrl: 'views/settings.html',
    controller: 'SettingsController',
    resolve: {
      avatars: function() {
        return APIProvider.$get().getAvatars();
      },
      householdData: function() {
        return APIProvider.$get().getHousehold();
      }
    }
  })
```

This works when there are no errors. I want to catch errors and have tried:

Settings Controller:

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function () {
    $location.path('/signin', false);
});
```

But this doesn't seem to trigger. Here are the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#$routeChangeError) I'm trying to use

FWIW, here is a sample of the API call:

```
var service = this;

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name API#doRequest
 * 
 * @description
 * utility function to handle $http actions. returns a promise
 */
function doRequest(path, method, data, opts) {
    var def = $q.defer(),
        args = [];

    if(['get','delete','post'].indexOf(method) === -1) { return def.reject();    }

    args.push(getUrl(path));
    if(data) { args.push(data ); }

    $http[method].apply(this, args)
        .success(function(data){
            def.resolve(data);
        })
        .error(function(){

            def.reject({ 'title': 'Connection problem.', 'subtitle': 'Please try your request again in a moment.'});
        });
    return def.promise;
}

 /**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name API#getHousehold
 * 
 * @description
 * requires access token in Household
 * returns promise with array of Households from server (should be only one)
 */
service.getHousehold = function() {
    // needs Household to have access token to work
    var def = $q.defer();

    if (typeof(Household.getAccessToken()) === 'undefined') {
        def.reject('Incorrect household id.');
        return def.promise;
    } else {
        var path = 'household/';
        return doRequest(path, 'get');
    }
};
```

**=========== WHAT WORKED =============**

this worked in app.js but am open to 'better' or more 'angular' solutions:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$location', function($rootScope, $location){
  'use strict';
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function() {
    $location.path('/signin', false);
  });
}])
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for either the `getAvatars()` or `getHousehold()` function?

Comment: updated. basically all of my API calls return a promise

Comment: Oh, your "what worked" explains it. You were adding the `$routeChangeError` handler in the `SettingsController`. But that controller doesn't get instantiated in the error scenario. If you want to handle all route change errors, you need to add the route change handler in the `.run` or somewhere before the controllers for UI Router states are instantiated. Sometimes, I have a top level `ApplicationController` that is not part of my UI-Router hierarchy, which would be another place to add the handler.

Comment: Sorry, I referred to UI Router above out of habit ... but the same concept applies w/the Angular Router :)